# Does Twilio API support multi-homing?

Tags: network-programming, twilio

If I create an application using twilio api to create a conference application between 5 users and each of the users are continuously changing network (switching between 4G / other Wi-fi networks ) . Will Twilio internally take care of seems less switching between (without any network disruption) them ? If yes, then how does it do that ? If not, how does the app developer ensure the service is not disrupted if the end point users are switching network.

Comment: How are the users dialling in to the conference? Via a normal mobile telephone call or via Twilio Client?

Comment: using the twilio client

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

If you are using Twilio Client in your app to call into the conference, then if the phone switches between 4G and wifi, we should keep the call going uninterrupted.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Could you provide more details on how does that work ? how Twilio is able to seemlessly switch between different networks without any interruption ?

Comment: Aslong as it's connected to the phone network it will just happen seamlessly - same as if you just browsing websites, on Facebook, etc. If you switch nothing happens